# ObjectListView (fast) - add new item only if same item does not exist

Tags: python, performance, objectlistview

How do I make sure only one occurence of an entry is added to the list? I want to disable another entry from being added if it matches some (specified) columns.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to prevent duplicates from being added to any widgets / data storage. The method I use occassionally is keeping track of the objects I have already added to something, such as an ObjectListView widget, and compare it with the new object I want to add. For example, lets create a tiny hex code generator.

```
import random

used_num = []

def gen_ran_num():
    val = ''.join([random.choice('0123456789ABCDEF') for x in range(6)])
    if val not in used_num:
        used_num.append(val)
        return val
```

In the code snippet a variable was created to store generated hex codes. The function generates a hexcode, then checks to see if the code has already been created. If the code does not already exist in the used_num variable it appends it then returns the value.

I think that you could use something like this to prevent duplicate information from being added to your ObjectListView.

When I have time I will edit my answer with some more sample code.

**--EDIT--**
Ok, here is a brief sample of my suggestion.

```
import wx
from ObjectListView import FastObjectListView, ColumnDefn

sample_data = (
    {'id': 1, 'days': 5, 'notes': 10},
    {'id': 2, 'days': 3, 'notes': 1},
    {'id': 3, 'days': 5, 'notes': 10},
    {'id': 4, 'days': 7, 'notes': 0},
    {'id': 5, 'days': 1, 'notes': 1},
    {'id': 1, 'days': 5, 'notes': 10},
    {'id': 2, 'days': 3, 'notes': 1},
    {'id': 2, 'days': 3, 'notes': 1},
    {'id': 1, 'days': 5, 'notes': 10},
    {'id': 4, 'days': 7, 'notes': 0},
    {'id': 6, 'days': 2, 'notes': 11}
  )

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY,
            title='Sample App')
        _pnl = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.dataOLV = FastObjectListView(_pnl, wx.ID_ANY,
                            style=wx.LC_REPORT|wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        self.dataOLV.Hide()
        self.added_to_olv = []
        _sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        _sizer.Add(self.dataOLV, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        _pnl.SetSizerAndFit(_sizer)
        self.SetColumns()
        self.SetData()
        self.Layout()

    def SetColumns(self):
        olvColumns = [
            ColumnDefn('ID',  'left', 155, 'id'),
            ColumnDefn('Issue Length', 'right', 35, 'days'),
            ColumnDefn('# of Notes', 'right', 35, 'notes')
        ]
        self.dataOLV.SetColumns(olvColumns)

    def SetData(self):
        for item in sample_data:
            if item['id'] not in self.added_to_olv:
                self.added_to_olv.append(item['id'])
                self.dataOLV.AddObject(item)
        self.dataOLV.RefreshObjects()
        self.dataOLV.Show()

def RunApp():
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MainFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    RunApp()
```

This example is using a dictionary to store the data that will be displayed in the ObjectListView. When the program is run it creates the FastObjectListView widget, and then hides it since it has no columns or data yet. It then runs a function to create the columns, followed by a function to populate and show the widget. I tested this sample app with up to 100 rows to be displayed and a varying amount of duplicates. It never showed the duplicate rows.

-Mike S